# IBM APIConnect - task security-appID

Tags: apiconnect

I have an instance of APIConnect on premise.

Analyzing the logs, I have seen the task called "security-appID" moving from 10ms execution time to 200ms execution time.

What is the meaning of this task?

Answer (score 0):

This task I believe offloads application security requests to other integrations if you have it so configured.  It does not have anything to do necessarily with apiconnect, it is probably related to your bluemix ID, dashboard or landing page and how that is setup.  You can probably find more information about it in the BMX docs.  https://console.dys0.bluemix.net/docs/services/appid/existing.html#adding-app-id-to-an-existing-app

Comment: thanks, but it is an on premise, standalone installation, not on bluemix.